# How to apply CSS style to custom React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I created a demo react app with 'npx create-react-app my-app'. When I try to apply style to React component nothing happens, but when I apply it to a normal HTML tag like `<div` or `<p>` it works. I do not why.

I also tried adding `:local` in the css file like: `:local(.taken-frame)`

```
// index.js =================        
import './style.css';


ReactDOM.render(
  <TakenFrame className="taken-frame"/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


// style.css ===============
.taken-frame{
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Css styles are applied to only JSX elements but not to the components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Css styles are applied to JSX elements in react but not to the component

Wrong way of applying css styles but className is still a valid prop to the component. You can access this using this.props.className and pass to the div as className like I mentioned in right way example

```
<TakenFrame className="taken-frame" />
```

Right way of applying css styles

```
 class TakenFrame extends React.Component {
       render(){
            return(
                <div className="taken-frame">

                </div>
                 //OR
               <div className={this.props.className}>

                </div>
            )
       }
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the right way to apply styles?

Comment: Creating a global one like by putting all the css into one file.css and use the classes wherever you want. Avoid doing inline css styles

Answer (score 2):

I use the following style:

```
import styles from 'yourstyles.css'

...

 class TakenFrame extends React.Component {
       render(){
            return(
                <div className={styles.classNameDeclaredInCssFile}>
                </div>
            )
       }
 }
```

yourstyles.css file should look something like:

```
.classNameDeclaredInCssFile{
//... your styles here
}
```

In your case you are simply passing a property called "className" to your component but not using it. In your component if you did something like:

```
 class TakenFrame extends React.Component {
       render(){
            return(
                <div className={this.props.className}>
                </div>
            )
       }
 }
```

It would work I expect but I prefer to keep my styles assigned to each component, I find it adds confusion for me as a developer when I am passing styles around the component hierarchy a lot. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use styled components as-well. Please refer https://glamorous.rocks/basics